# Using the `:set` and `:initialize` keywords of `defcustom`

Tags: defcustom

I recently [encountered a situation](https://github.com/anler/centered-window-mode/commit/2e9bc717ce962789a49c97a23bf2674a0f14b954) in which specifying a `:set` function for a `defcustom` raised a `Symbol's function definition is void` error.

This is because the `:set` function relies on another function in the same package, which is not yet loaded when the `defcustom` is initialized.

The way I handled this is to explicitly define the `:initialize` function to be `custom-initialize-default`. Is this the best way? If I wanted to use the `:set` function for initialization, how best to do that[1]?

[1]: Elisp does not have forward declaration AFAIK; `declare-function` doesn't seem to work for functions in the same file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the `:set` function is not appropriate also for initialization, explicitly provide a different `:initialize` function. Using `custom-initialize-default` is a common use case for this.

If you really do not want to do that, but you want to use just `:set`, then your `:set` function will need to do the necessary initialization, either conditionally or systematically.  You might have a use case for this, but it would likely be unusual. It is by design that initialization stuff is separated from the rest, by making `:initialize` available.